# antd Pagination Component 'onChange' API don't call when browser back or fore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, antd

browser back or fore can't call 'onChange' API, so that the page list can't update according to current page

```
onPageChange = (page, pageSize) => {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    const param = {
        blogId: this.props.params.id,
        pageIdx: page,
        quantity: pageSize
    }
    dispatch(fetchIssues('getComments', param, ''))
    hashHistory.push({
        pathname: `/post/${this.props.params.id}`,
        query: { pageIdx: page }
    })
}
render() {
    return <Pagination onChange={onPageChange} total={50} />
}
```

Comment: What if replace `onChange={onPageChange}` with `onChange={this.onPageChange}`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to take into account the browser back or fore click event. that event call `popstate` The popstate event is fired each time when the current history entry changes (user navigates to a new state). That happens when user clicks on browser's Back/Forward buttons or when `history.back()`, `history.forward()`, `history.go()` methods are programatically called.

in Javascript

window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) var r = confirm("You pressed a Back button! Are you sure?!");

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
    // The popstate event is fired each time when the current history entry changes.

    if (r == true) {
        // Call Back button programmatically as per user confirmation.
        history.back();
        // Uncomment below line to redirect to the previous page instead.
        // window.location = document.referrer // Note: IE11 is not supporting this.
    } else {
        // Stay on the current page.
        history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    }

    history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have show the all `total` 50 items in current page. The current page number will not change and `onChange` then not invoked.